# Upgrading neo4j to 3.0 without loosing page cache

Tags: neo4j

Is there a way to migrate data or upgrade existing server without loosing the current page cache?

We tried many times but it seems like we must to warm-up the new server for a long time before we can actually use it.

What should be the best practice to upgrade without a long downtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if it were possible to retain the page cache (which I seriously doubt), it is not reasonable to expect that the new (and significantly changed) DB software would be able to use it.

If you are not already using it, the [neo4j-warmup](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-warmup) plugin might be helpful in getting your DB warmed up more quickly.

Comment: I will give it a try.. I'm using some general query which takes a lot of time to warm up the server: MATCH (n)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]->()
RETURN count(n.id) + count(r.id);

Comment: Works much better. thanks. I think Neo4j must add this plugin to the core. Server warm up without this plugin can take forever.
thanks